# Problems getting built-in 3G modem (Ericsson H5321gw – USB ID 0bdb:1926) working on my Lenovo X230 (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, gnome3, wwan

I have Ericsson H5321gw WWAN modem (USB ID 0bdb:1926) on my Lenovo X230 laptop. I've got it working momentarily using NetworkManager GUI on Gnome3. Normally I can make it connect for a few minutes only to see the whole device being removed from NetworkManager later by itself. So technically it is working, but somehow the device keeps getting removed after a while (causing disconnection, of course). Initially I thought this might be an issue of USB Autosuspend power saving functionality but I have tried setting it off like so:

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend; do echo -1 > $i; done
```

I have Debian Jessie with 3.10-3-amd64 kernel.

This is an example log from test where I got disconnected right away after connecting: http:// pastebin.com/ bGbTHGri (url pasting limit, sorry)

This is another test where I got disconnected after being connected for about 2 minutes:

- /var/log/kern.log: http://pastebin.com/wkQkkYrA
- /var/log/syslog: http://pastebin.com/Hx8aJqvx

Comment: same problem here - did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured this out. You need to:

```
sudo cp /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

and then edit it to add an entry matching your card's lsusb output. That solved this for me.
Full blurb on my http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2015/03/fixed-linux-ericsson-h5321gw-3ggpshspa.html

Comment: I gave up with the WWAN modem and started to use tethering on my cell phone instead. I'll try this out sometime and see if it works. Thanks for input!

Comment: PS: Note http://askubuntu.com/questions/592988/how-to-fix-resume-issue-usbhid-2-41-0-cant-add-hid-device-110 re. a (minor..) suspend/resume issue I'm seeing with this card.